# Java design issue: enum with underlying class

Tags: java, enums

I have an `enum` where each member is a `Set<String>`, i.e. the following is my code:

```
// Guava used only for the ease of "Sets<E>.newHashSet(E... elements)", no other
// reason.
// For pre-Java8 code, the toString() method needs to be changed.
public enum MyEnum {
  MemberOne(Sets.newHashSet("this", "is", "the", "first", "member")),
  MemberTwo(Sets.newHashSet("this", "is", "the", "second", "member", "and", "it",
                            "has", "some", "more", "words"));

  private Set<String> elements;

  private MyEnum(Set<String> elements) { this.elements = elements; }

  public toString() {
    return elements.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
  }
}
```

I have `MyEnum` because I want to have only a highly specific set of strings elsewhere in the project, where others should not be using a method with arbitrary `Set<String>`. But, I would also like to retain the functionalities of sets, i.e., I would like to be able to do something like

```
if (MyEnum.MemberOne.contains("some_random_word"))
  doSomethingSpecificToWordsInMemberOne();
```

Right now, I am thinking of adding a method `public Set<String> toSet() { return elements; }` to do this, mainly because `elements` should not be public.

Is this a good way to design? Should I be doing something totally different? E.g.

- having a class with a bunch of `static final Set<String>` objects (my least favorite option)
- have `elements` as `public final` (my favorite option right now)

My code has sets as enum members, but my doubt pertains to any situation where `Set<String>` is replaced with some other class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's an `enum` it makes sense to have elements as `public final`. To avoid problems  you could ensure an additional constraint:

```
public final Set<String> elements;

private MyEnum(Set<String> elements) {
  this.elements = Collections.unmodifiableSet(elements);
}
```

So that you will be still allowed to call methods that alter the set but you would get an `UnsupportedOperationException`. If you want compile time safety about this you should bridge the methods of the set which should be available to clients and nothing more.

```
private final Set<String> elements;

public boolean contains(String string) { return elements.contains(string); }
public String[] elements() { return elements.toArray(new String[elements.size()]; }
...
```

Comment: Good answer, esp. the use of unmodifiableSet.

Comment: +1 - I would also suggest using `Set<E extends Enum<E>>` instead of `Set<String>` but that's just me.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: Could you please explain this a bit more? I was looking at the source code of `EnumSet`, and I intuitively feel that `Set<E extends Enum<E>>` should be something I do, but while trying to implement it, I got super-confused and gave up. Pointer to good tutorial/examples will also be appreciated. Googling wasn't much of a help here.

Comment: @ChthonicProject - I was just suggesting using `enum`s instead of `String`s if possible. It retains a further level of type safety.